# How do I set wp_mail arguments/manually force wp_mail sending based on the sender's email address?

Tags: wp-mail

I need a way to query the sender's email address before delivery is attempted, and then set wp_mail arguments depending on the results.

So something like the following:

- If sender_email contains @domain.com then continue
- Else, if sender_email doesn't contain @domain.com, update wp_mail headers before sending

Use case is basically this:

I'm authenticating domain email using Postmark, so email will only send successfully if the sender's address matches an authenticated domain in my Postmark account.

What I want to do is create a check before it tries to send through Postmark, and if it's not an authenticated email address then send using wp_mail (WordPress's default mailing system) instead.

Or, put another way, ONLY send email through Postmark if it matches a specific domain or email address (which we can set manually).

Comment: Are you using some plugin to connect your WP site with Postmark or have you written custom code for it? The first things that come to my mind are the `wp_mail` filter and `phpmailer_init` action that you could perhaps take a look at.

Comment: Hey @AnttiKoskinen! I'm using Postmark's own plugin, which links with their API. But according to them I can override Postmark's sending by setting wp_mail headers. I just need to run an "if" check to check the sender's email before I do.

Answer (score 1):

Perhpaps `wp_mail`would be a suitable filter for this case as it is the first one to fire in `wp_mail()`. So perhaps something as simple as this might work,

```
// For reference:
// $atts = array(
//   'to' => string, 
//   'subject' => string, 
//   'message' => string, 
//   'headers' => string or array (I think), 
//   'attachments' => array,
// );
function filter_wp_mail( $atts ) {
  if ( false === strpos( '@domain.com', $atts['to'] ) ) {
    $atts['headers'] .= "Postmark: not valid email\n";
  }
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'filter_wp_mail' );
```